# Google Analytics - exclude outliers days in sessions graph

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, statistics

How can I exclude outliers days (spikes) in a Google analytics graph (sessions from organic search per day) ? I've had 2 very good days but those spikes make the graph very hard to read. See the graph below.

[image: analytics graph with spikes]

Comment: I don't think that GA has functionality for excluding certain days.  Are you willing to download the data and create a graph yourself?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks hadn't thought of that for some reason. Not ideal, not really a solution but I got the graph i wanted anyway by exporting to excel.